# TextField com valor inicial no ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Não estou conseguindo identificar o erro na especificação no XML, a cada caractere adicionado na inicialização do TextField, que está dentro do ConstraintLayout, o LinearLayout raiz aumenta a altura.

Antecipadamente agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O layout com fundo vermelho, que contem o Título e o ContraintLayout, é o seguinte:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/r500">
```

O interno é este

```
<include layout="@layout/main_dialog_title"/>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layout_margin10"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_margin20"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/layout_margin10"
    android:background="@color/g500">

    <TextView
        style="@style/label"
        android:id="@+id/labCod"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/codigo"/>

    <lib.client.control.CTextField
        style="@style/textField"
        android:id="@+id/txfCod"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/labCod"

        android:text="AAA_A"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/label"
        android:id="@+id/labNom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin10"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txfCod"
        android:text="@string/nome"/>

    <lib.client.control.CTextField
        style="@style/textField"

        android:id="@+id/txfNom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/labNom"/>

    <lib.client.control.CLabelCount
        style="@style/labelCount"
        android:id="@+id/labCnt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txfNom"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/txfNom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txfNom"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/btnOkk"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txfNom"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Como o ConstraintLayout e o código do modal se comunicam? Edita e coloca o código inteiro como você está utilizando.